# SVN: How to get log of modified files names from first revision using SVN?

Tags: svn

I want to prepare list of file names which are modified and added by developer from beginning of the project. Project is setup on SVN.

So, How can i getting modified/added file list from first revision of SVN?

Answer (score 0):

With svn log, you can see all the commits and comment.

It's good for you?

Like this if yo want write on a file : `svn log > log.txt`

Answer (score 0):

> svn diff -r --summarize

If you are interested only in added/modified files, you may want also add some filtering to remove records about deletions.

Or in TortoiseSVN select two revisions and compare them (from context menu).